# Image ontop of div

Tags: css, html

I have multiple divs

```
.barinfo {
float:left;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
width: 768px;
height: 540px;
background:#000;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
display: none;
}
.mosaic-overlay {
    z-index:5;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#000;
}
.details { 
margin:15px 20px; 
}
```

and I want a image to cover it. The image has left and right arrows so user can click on it to navigate through the divs mentioned above.

How can i make the image completely independent of anything so it is ontop of the div? Right now it just gets pushed to the right side or bottom of the div

Any method of doing so is fine

HTML CODE:

```
<div id="bar5info" class="barinfo">
    <div class="mosaic-overlay"><img onload="imageLoaded()" src="images/Seg1.png" /></div>
    <div class="details">
        <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
</div>
<img src="arrows.png" /> <!--the arrows ontop of the divs-->
```

Comment: we are going to need html code to answer.

Comment: You probably need position:absolute on that img

Answer (score 1):

Wrap everything in a container, put `position:relative` on the container, and  `position:absolute` on the arrow images. Then use the `left`, `right`, `top`, and `bottom` properties to position the arrows relative to the container's grid.

See [Absolute Positioning Inside Relative Positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) for an overview of this approach

Comment: a fiddle demo will be more helpful and understandable here

Comment: I can't change the position: of the barinfo and mosaicoverlay

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `position:absolute` to make image independent of all & use accordingly...but more specifically html code will be good to work on ....Thanks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Simple set position:absolute and after that you can set left,right bottom and top whatever you like ...and there you are u can easily set your image/div or any HTML element on one another...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `position:absolute` to take off the image from the page and then use `top:__px` and `left:__px` to position the image in the page.

If you want to refer the position to an element you have to add `position:relative` to these element.

Comment: position:absolute doesnt work the img is still being pushed around by the divs

Comment: does not work, the image is getting pushed around by the divs